# Dynamic width for each column if value is 0 in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, highcharts

I'm new to highcharts plugin and I need to set different width for each column if the value is empty.

```
series: [{   
 name: 'Jane',
  data: [1, 0, 4]
 }, {
  name: 'John',
  data: [5, 7, 3]
 }]
```

And i need to display it this way

[I need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcCqP.png)

I have been searching the documentation but i don't find anything that does it, without a lot of code.

I achieved this, but it doesn't upload/resize dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/5vgjztk0/

Thanks

Comment: So for example, in your jsfiddle, you want the bar over February in the graph to be wider and dynamically resize on window resize?

Comment: From a user experience perspective, I'm not sure why you would want to do this. If I looked at the example you gave, I would wonder what was wrong with the "Bananas" column. To truthfully display your data with null values, you should instead consider adding a data label to show that the value is null or zero, rather than "fattening" up the other column.

Comment: You can use something like merimekko chart, http://jsfiddle.net/js55fuo1/24/

Comment: @SebastianBochan I think i can work with that! thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like merimekko chart.

```
(function(H) { 
    var each = H.each;

       var xStart = 0;
var rememberX = 0;       
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'drawPoints', function(proceed) {
        var series = this;
        if(series.data.length > 0 ){
            each(this.data, function(point) {
                point.shapeArgs.width = series.xAxis.translate(point.x) - series.xAxis.translate(xStart);
                point.shapeArgs.x = series.xAxis.translate(point.x) - point.shapeArgs.width; 
                xStart = point.x;
            });
            xStart = 0;
        }
        proceed.call(this);
    })
})(Highcharts)
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/js55fuo1/24